# passing callback to custom react hook

Tags: react-hooks

I have a custom hook that creates a web worker and registers a callback with the worker:

```
const useMyHook(callback){ 
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let worker = /// create worker
    worker.onmessage = callback
  }, [callback])
}
```

to use the hook, the user has to know to wrap the callback in `React.useCallback` or each render will create a new worker.

```
const callback = React.useCallback(() => doSomething())
useMyHook(callback)
```

How can I update my hook so the user can simply pass an anonymous func `useMyHook(() => doSomething())`

Answer (score 3):

Set the callback on a ref, and update it in another `useEffect` block.

Remove the callback's  dependency of the worker's `useEffect()`, and call the callback from the `cb.current`.

```
const useMyHook(callback){ 
  const cb = useRef(callback)
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    cb.current = callback
  })

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const worker = /// create worker
    worker.onmessage = (...args) => cb.current(...args)
  }, [])
}
```